# Как запустить свой .exe после окончания установки созданного с inno setup?

Tags: python, inno-setup

Я хочу привязать свой .exe file в установщик Python. Чтобы после завершения установки он запускал мой .exe file. Как это сделать ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3767227/1216425

Comment: @teran Можно было бы развёрнуто написать, чтоб наполнить сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте инсталлятор для своего .exe и положите в свой инсталлятор установщик Python. В справке на inno-setup есть пример как распаковать из инсталлятора и запустить что-то во время установки.

Установщик Python наверняка имеет параметры запуска для "тихой" установки. После успешной установки Python и своего .exe, запускаете прямо из инсталлятора свой .exe (пример по ссылке из комментария к вашему вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3767227/1216425)